# Is it possible to view who all are visited my profile?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, views

In profile there is a column called **"profile views"**. Is it possible to view who all are visited my profile.. Thank you

Comment: Anything is *possible*, yes. But why would you want this implemented?

Comment: possible??? but community wiki member oded said not possible.. because i can improve my thought and question who all are interested to me.. so i can get answer quickly

Comment: It is 'possible' in the sense that it could be developed. But you haven't said why you want this feature and what benefit it would have.

Comment: @JonW: There is no `feature-request` tag on this post, so the OP is perhaps not asking for it to be developed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there is now. (Yet it's still lacking the *why* part).

Comment: @JonW because i can improve my thought and question who all are interested to me.. easily share and get responsible quicker

Comment: @prabhakaran That wouldn't do what you want it to do, and you shouldn't be targeting your content for specific users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

We are also not likely to add such an option - Stack Exchange sites try *very* hard to not be social networks, but focus on questions and answers over user interactions.

Comment: oh ok but community wiki members can view rite

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Or how Community Wiki has anything to do with profile views.

Comment: I wonder if @prabhakaran means Community Moderators or Managers? If so, prabhakaran: Moderators can not. Devs/managers could find that if it was needed, but they wouldn't give that information to a user, and wouldn't even bother looking unless there were some security issue.